# Stack overflow when opening a serial connection using boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio, labview

I'm trying to connect to a device on COM3 and the code runs until I call `open("COM3")`, which causes a stack overflow. Here's the relevant code:

```
asio::io_service io;
asio::basic_serial_port<asio::serial_port_service> scope(io);

//Open the connection and configure it
cout << "OPENING\n";
system::error_code error;
scope.open(PORT, error);
```

After opening the connection I configure it with the baud rate, etc.

It's hanging in win_iocp_serial_port_service.ipp, inside of SetCommState(handle, &dcb).

I also have some labview code to connect, send a command, and disconnect, which works. If I've run the labview code since starting up my computer, then my C++ program works (connects without hanging), but if I haven't yet run the labview code it gives me a stack overflow. This makes me think that I'm not starting up some driver or setting something persistent but I'm not sure what it would be.
If anyone's run into this issue or has any insight I appreciate the help!

Info from further testing: Connecting from non-labview serial connection clients seems to enable boost to connect as well. If I first connect via hyperterminal it works, and if I connect via command line (per this guide https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/command-line-windows-mac-linux) then I can subsequently connect via boost as well, which might be a workable solution, even if its dumb. Unfortunately I couldn't successfully send data with System.IO.Ports.SerialPort so the temporary solution is connect using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort, disconnect, then connect using boost asio now that it works. This works reasonably well but the code now only works on windows.

Comment: This is on Windows? Is your serial port a "real" port or a USB/serial adapter kind of thing? What if you have a program other than Labview operate on the port before your program, but after a fresh boot?

Comment: It is on windows, with a USB/serial adapter. I haven't yet tried using another program to connect first - that's a good idea. I'll check it out!

Comment: I'll let you know that those USB adapters are flaky. They go to sleep, and seem to change port numbers if you unplug them sometimes. I'm betting Labview is doing something to poke the adapter and get it to wake up. Other than that hint (which might not even help) I don't have anything more for you... Good luck!

Comment: I tested it with HyperTerminal and that had the same functionality as labview. i.e. connected fine off a fresh boot, and afterwards my c++ program could connect as well. I'll poke around and see if I can find anything about the adapter going to sleep/how to wake it up... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use your serial instrument from LabVIEW, your hypothesis that you're *"not starting up some driver or setting something persistent"* is probably correct.

You can see how LabVIEW and VISA are configuring the port and sending commands using a tool provided by NI called **I/O Trace** [1]. Once you have the working settings and commands in hand, you can match them with your calls to `boost::asio` and determine if you are over- or under-configuring the port.

In the I/O trace logs, you'll see VISA setting the baud, flow control, and the other traits before opening a session. The driver doesn't share much more than that, however, so if your program is using the same settings and sequence but still hanging, then scrutinize how you're programming to the `asio` interface [2].

> ### References
>
> **[1] Performing a Good NI I/O Trace Capture for Debugging/Troubleshooting**
>   
> http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/282C5D41E2BA04F2862574BA007803B9
>
> **[2] Serial ports and C++**
>   
> http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html